# Select a element inside a variable containing html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to select a particular div element and later transfer that div element to a new html file so that i could convert it into pdf,

The problem with me is that I am using ajax and my html code contains various tab and basically it is a management system,

Just to give you a general idea

```
 $('#print_repo').on('click',function(e){
   var officer_id = $('#officer-id').val();
    $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
       url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>Home/ajax_view', 
        data: {'id':officer_id}, 
       success: function(resp) { 
        // b=resp;
        console.log($(resp > "#personal"));
        // console.log($($(resp) >$("#personal")));
        // console.log($(resp->"#personal"));
        // console.log(resp);
      }
  });
});
```

This is an ajax call the resp contains my html code whole html file including the script tag that i have used I want to select 2 forms whose id's 
are `personal and work_info`
one for example
`<?=form_open(base_url()."Home/insert_work_infos/","id=\"work_info\"");?>`

But I am unable to select it inside `resp`, Output of `resp` if I use `console.log(resp);` is :

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
      ....
<div class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" id="one"class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"id="two"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" ></i> Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" id='three'><a href="#status" class="hiddd" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Status</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
                      <form action="http://project2.com/Home/insert_personal" id="personal" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            .................

            <button id="b1" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-inline btn-lg" tabindex="11" disabled>SUBMIT</button></div>
          </form>            </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">



        <form action="http://project2.com/Home/insert_work_infos/" id="work_info" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        ....... 
         ........
          <button type="button" onclick="javascript:back(); " data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-default" data-target="#home">BACK</button>

        </div>
        <hr class="colorgraph">
        <button type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="b2"class="btn btn-primary btn-inline-block btn-lg center-block"disabled >SUBMIT</button>

      </form>        </div>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  // yearRange: '1950:2013',
  yearRange: "c-70:c+10"
});
  .......
 </script>
```

Comment: What about `$(resp).find("#personal")` or `$(resp).filter("#personal")`.

Comment: Perfect just write an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `find()` or `filter()` methods :

```
$(resp).find("#personal");
//OR
$(resp).filter("#personal");
```

Hope this helps.